# FileCopyUtils or IOUtils

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

***Long story short*:**

> What is the difference between Spring's `FileCopyUtils.copy()` and
>   Apache Commons's `IOUtils.copy()`?

***Full Story*:**

Recently, when developing a Web app with SpringMVC 4, I had to implement a controller that sends a file to the user browser. I'm accessing the file and creating a `InputStream` that is redirected by calling `HttpServletResponse.getOutputStream()`. I found two ways of copying my input stream to the output stream, one is using Spring's `FileCopyUtils.copy(inputstream, outputstream)` and the other is using Apache Common's `IOUtils.copy(inputstream, outputstream)` (or largeCopy() for files over 2GB).

Is there any real differences between both classes/methods? As far as I can see Javadocs just refer to copying the input stream to the output and not requiring manual closing.

Comment: IMHO both methods are bad because of the very small copy buffer size of 4KB.

Comment: @Robert any thoughts on alternatives?

Comment: for example: write 2 lines of code that do the same but with a bigger buffer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you compare the source, they're almost identical, except that Spring calls `flush()` on the output stream when it's done.

Comment: Therefore springs util has more impact considering memory performance